# StackExchange Redis .NET client not getting messages when connections are reordered

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Using the StackExchange.Redis client in a C# application, I am attempting to use PubSub to perform cross-server communication between web servers running the same application.  In this model, each server is running its own Redis server, and its connection multiplexer sets the local server as the first server in the list.  In other words, SERVER_A and SERVER_B each run a Redis server on port 6379 and have connection strings as follows:

```
SERVER_A --> "SERVER_A:6379,SERVER_B:6379"
SERVER_B --> "SERVER_B:6379,SERVER_A:6379"
```

Using external clients to subscribe to each Redis server, I can see SERVER_A publishing messages to its local Redis server.  However, SERVER_B is not picking up the message, despite having a connection via the multiplexer.  When I rearrange the order of the connections so they match, then messages from A are picked up by B.  Is there something in a setting or otherwise that I need to do so that the connection multiplexer will listen to subscriptions on all servers, or is this a bug in the StackExchange.Redis client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention any replication in your description. When SE.Redis connects to multiple servers it is intended to be a *related family* of servers - for example, either:

- two or more 2.* servers related via master/slave
- three or more 3.* servers related via a formal cluster

Replication groups have distribution mechanisms for pub/sub. Two disconnected servers: do not.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense; our setup doesn't have a formal cluster because we are running Redis on Windows, and we can't use Master/Slave because each Redis server needs to be writable.  We actually kinda mock the Master/Slave by having our application write to both Redis servers using an `IEnumerable<ConnectionMultiplexer>` and read from then using a single ConnectionMultiplexer configured as stated in question.  We are just getting into PubSub and couldn't figure out what was going on.

Comment: @saluce there *is* an option that allows slaves to be writeable, but that will mean they diverge and won't be a true master/slave - also, publish on the master would go to the slave, but publish on the slave does not get to the master. There has been an interesting discussion on the redis mailing list this week about multi-master replication (different to cluster), but that is just a random spike by a 3rd party, and certainly won't exist in the MSOpenTech windows version.